# How to create a distributed application on elixir?

Tags: erlang-otp, elixir

I'm a bit new to elixir and i'm not entirely sure what i'm doing wrong. I'm looking to create a distributed application (runninng on one of several nodes)

I've been looking at the erlang documentation and the elixir documentaiton but i don't seem to be able to get it working.

Any help would be greatly apreciated

**Application**

```
defmodule ShortCode  do
  use Application

  require Stout

  # for more information on OTP Applications
  def start do
    :application.start(:short_code)
  end

  def start(_type, _args) do
    ShortCode.Supervisor.start_link
  end
end
```

**Supervisor**

```
defmodule ShortCode.Supervisor do
  require Stout

  use Supervisor

  @worker_name :short_code_generator


  def start_link do
    :supervisor.start_link({:global, __MODULE__}, __MODULE__, [])
  end

  def init([]) do

    children = [
      worker(ShortCode.Generator, [], [restart: :permanent])
    ]

    # for other strategies and supported options
    supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end

  def generate_short_code do
    ShortCode.Generator.generate_short_code
  end
end
```

**Worker**

```
defmodule ShortCode.Generator do
  require Stout

  use GenServer


  def start_link() do
    :gen_server.start_link({:global, :short_code_generator}, __MODULE__, [], [])
  end

  def generate_short_code do
    :gen_server.call({:global, __MODULE__}, :generate)
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What's not working? I assume by the ... in your worker module you're not showing the whole thing? Do you have a `handle_call` callback do handle the call?

Comment: Do the nodes see each-other (`Node.list`)?

Comment: I'd assume that the Problem is not in your code but in how you run it. Have a look at http://elixir-lang.org/getting_started/mix_otp/10.html it should point you in the right direction.